# Selecting column name for frequency count in sqlite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a table in sqlite that contains roughly about 3 billion values (a lot of them will be repeats). It's basically a giant vector of values. I'm trying to calculate the frequency in which values appear in the table by performing this:-

```
SELECT abs(diffs), count(*) as total FROM mzdiff GROUP by abs(diffs);
```

abs(diffs) is the name of my column and mzdiff is my table name, but when I try performing the code above it comes up with an error message saying that the column diffs doesn't exist. I know that the naming of my column isn't really ideal for sql, but is there any way I can get around this?

Thanks

Comment: Try giving it an alias: SELECT abs(diffs) as absdiff, COUNT(1) as total FROM mzdiff GROUP BY absdiff;

Also, COUNT(1) is a tad bit faster than COUNT(*)

Comment: Learn about quoting identifiers, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: An sqlite table with 3B values... How is that working out?

Comment: Unsurprisingly frustrating :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is not an alias since the column name must be identified before it can be aliased so use the backtick to quote the name and make it a habit to always quote identifiers.

```
SELECT `abs(diffs)`, count(*) as total FROM `mzdiff` GROUP by `abs(diffs)`;
```